# Magento 2 questions tagged beta, alpha, pre-alpha etc. - quo vadis?

Tags: discussion, tags, magento2, retagging

There are lots of Magento 2 questions from the pre-release era and I was wondering what to do with them.

Many technical details have changed since then and nobody uses these versions anymore, so the tags have at most historical relevance.

### So here's my proposal:

- Re-tag questions where the answers are still valid in Magento 2.0 (remove the old version tag, add [magento-2.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-2.0)
- close questions where the answers are only valid for pre-release versions. We did the same with Magento Go questions when the service was discontinued
- additionally, if the question has high views, try to find one on the topic that's up to date and link it

Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds good to me. Let's go for it.

Comment: Seconded. I'm in favor.

Comment: I'm in too, let's do this

Comment: Hmmmm should we go for [tag:magento-2.0] or [tag:magento2] ?

Comment: Also @Marius you should probably update this one: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79/are-magento-2-0-questions-allowed

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism. I did something better. I closed that question.

Comment: Same attempt for third party tags: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/q/905/3326

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done my share on a few tags. I have also removed the tags from **closed** questions because if you are tagging your question and type "magento2-" you still see them appearing in the suggestions with a >0 count.

Only [magento2-dev-beta](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-dev-beta) is still left with a large number of questions.

- [magento2-pre-alpha](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-pre-alpha) > 0 questions
- [magento2-alpha](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-alpha) > 0 questions
- [magento2-alpha93](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-alpha93) > 0 questions
- [magento2-alpha96](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-alpha96) > 0 questions
- [magento2-alpha105](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-alpha105) > 0 questions
- **[magento2-dev-beta](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-dev-beta) > 148 questions**
- [magento2-merchant-beta](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-merchant-beta) > 0 questions
- [magento2-rc](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-rc) > 0 questions
- [2.0.0.0-dev55](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2.0.0.0-dev55) > 0 questions

Comment: yes I've done some questions as well, I'll get back to it re: the dev-beta tag

Answer (score 4):

Great, approved by 2/3 mods.

So if anybody wants to actively help out, these are the tags that I could find:

- [magento2-pre-alpha](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-pre-alpha)
- [magento2-alpha](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-alpha)
- [magento2-alpha93](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-alpha93)
- [magento2-alpha96](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-alpha96)
- [magento2-alpha105](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-alpha105)
- [magento2-dev-beta](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-dev-beta)
- [magento2-merchant-beta](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-merchant-beta)
- [magento2-rc](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2-rc)
- [2.0.0.0-dev55](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2.0.0.0-dev55)

Answer (score 1):

Also, maybe we should create tag synonyms for those tags so no one use them in the future.